# shap.DeepExplainer Error : TFDeep' object has no attribute ' between_tensors' Exception encountered when calling layer lstm

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, shap

I use shap.DeepExplainer and I got an error

I open issue on https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/2808

```
    AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lstm" "                 f"(type LSTM).
    
    'TFDeep' object has no attribute 'between_tensors'
    
    Call arguments received by layer "lstm" "                 f"(type LSTM):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(4184, 44, 4), dtype=float32)
      • mask=None
      • training=False
      • initial_state=None
```

This is my code , the part of model construction   and invoking Shap

```
model = Sequential()

n_neurons = x_train.shape[1] * x_train.shape[2]
print(n_neurons, x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])

model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')


history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                        batch_size=batch_size, 
                        epochs=epochs,shuffle=False,
                        validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
                       )
```

```
import shap
# Use the training data for deep explainer => can use fewer instances
explainer_ = shap.DeepExplainer(model, x_train)
shap_values_ = explainer_.shap_values(x_test)
```

[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you find a solution?